# 2002 Toyota 4Runner intermittent HVAC issue

Tags: hvac

2002 Toyota 4Runner intermittently starts blowing hot air no matter where temp setting is at. Fiddling with temperature knob resolves issue.

Comment: Question?  I assume it's, "Why?" but it would be best to state it in the question for clarity's sake. Thanks, and welcome aboard!

Comment: The first place I would look is the "blend door motor".  There is a door that swings back and forth to adjust the air from hot to cold and places in between.  The motor is a little, either vacuum or electrically (more common these days) operated.  That can fail and it will allow the door to move on its own.